# Twilio's Device.connect method returns null connection in Android

Tags: android, twilio, voip, twilio-twiml

I am following Twilio's Android quickstart tutorial for an Android app. Here is the link to the tutorial:
https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/android-client/make-outgoing-call

I am trying to make an outgoing call. I have set up a trial account with a Twiml application. I have set the URL to the token, and the URL to the /call endpoint that serves Twilio's xml.

I am receiving the token, and the Device object's status is ready.

But whenever I call Device.connect, I get the following errors:
Connecting new call failed
java.lang.NullPointerExpection
at java util.HashMap.

Here is the code I am using:

```
Connection connection = device.connect(null /* parameters */, null /* ConnectionListener */);
                        if (connection == null){
                            Log.e("failed to connect", "Failed to create new connection");  
                        }
```

Comment: I found the solution. Looks like Twilio does not allow null parameters for the connect method. So I just filled dummy parameters:
"To" : "1" , and it worked.

Comment: So your app doesn't crash anymore  after this?

Comment: Yes, just add these before the connect method:
  Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<String, String>();
   parameters.put("dummy","dummy");
and it should work. It could be a different error, but this solved it for me.

Comment: I cannnot put dummy because I'm sending group id here with the key and value in parameters.

Comment: My application works fine but sometimes it crashes on `connection = device.connect(parameters, null);`

Comment: you can add as many parameters as you need. The idea is that it cannot be null ( or I could be mistaken) .

To find the error, you need to place logs in the connection listener to see where exactly it crashes, and what errors it gives. It could be anything!

Comment: I get `java.lang.NullPointerException` here every time when it crashes.

Comment: Can you see exactly where does the NUllPointerException happens? what line?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79420/discussion-between-anshul-tyagi-and-pacemaker).

Comment: Okay, Let me know when you are available

Comment: Don't worry, i have solved my problem 3 days ago.

Answer (score 0):

```
I also had the same problem but by adding elements to hashmap and passing the map to connect method resolved my problem.
public void connect()
    {
        HashMap<String, String> hash=new HashMap<String, String>();
        hash.put("To", "22");
        connection=device.connect(hash, null);
        if(connection==null)
            Log.w(TAG, "Failed to create new connection");
    }
```